# Create object from related Class or it's own Class?

Tags: python, class, orm, model

I find that when I am creating the downstream object I am doing most of the work by retroactively going back to the higher entity.

```py
Class State(BaseModel):
    ...


Class City(BaseModel):
    ...
    def create_from_state(state_id:int, city_name):
        # Manipulate some data from State.
        # Then finally a quick `City.create(attributes)`.
```

Should I instead be doing the `create()` from the other model?

```py
Class State(BaseModel):
    ...

    def create_city(id, city_name):


Class City(BaseModel):
    ...
```

---

Here's what the different options look like:

`City.create_from_state(state_id=s_id, city_name='Boston')`

vs

`my_state.create_city(city_name=Boston)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are sharing some attributes between City and State, being that the reason you inherit both from a common BaseModel.

I think it is better to just have a City and a State models, no common parent, and then pass a reference to the state when you create a city. Then you can access the attributes you need from the state reference, just before creation, or when initiating the city.

A city *has a* state, and the state has many cities in a (State 1:M  City) relationship.